# Return index of each match between columns based on a filter for a third column

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

For each row with category "AR" in column `movement_type`, I want to check whether the corresponding value from the column `end_datetime` is contained in column `start_datetime` for records of category "PK" (also contained in column `movement_type`). I then want to have the index of that "PK" record.

I tried to make two sets of data, a `df_amove_AR` and a `df_amove_PK`, and then to run a loop with an `if` condition. However, this returned nothing, while I know that this is not possible (there are at least about 50 matches).

The loop I built:

```
df_amove_AR = df_amove[df_amove["movement_type"] == "AR"]
df_amove_PK = df_amove[df_amove["movement_type"] == "PK"]

for ar in df_amove_AR.index: 
    end_AR = df_amove_AR.at[ar, "end_datetime"]
    if end_AR in df_amove_PK["start_datetime"]:
        print(df_amove_PK["start_datetime"].index)
```

Both `end_datetime` and `start_datetime` are `datetime` columns. Does anyone have an idea why my loop is not returning any matches? Does anyone have a suggestion for building the "AR" and "PK" filter in?

(FYI: the goal is to make matches of AR+PK with corresponding end and start times)

Sample data for one aircraft registration or `acreg` at one day:

| acreg | flight | movement_type | start_datetime | end_datetime | current_position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PHTFM | OR1072 | AR | 2022-08-08 02:24:44 | 2022-08-08 02:29:32 | D02 |
| PHTFM | OR377 | DP | 2022-08-08 14:23:51 | 2022-08-08 14:42:22 | D07 |
| PHTFM | None | PK | 2022-08-08 04:27:00 | 2022-08-08 12:04:00 | U21 |
| PHTFM | None | MV | 2022-08-08 04:07:00 | 2022-08-08 04:27:00 | U21 |
| PHTFM | None | MV | 2022-0 8-08 12:04:00 | 2022-08-08 12:15:00 | D07 |
| PHTFM | None | PK | 2022-08-08 02:29:32 | 2022-08-08 04:07:00 | D02 |
| PHTFM | None | PK | 2022-08-08 12:15:00 | 2022-08-08 14:23:51 | D07 |

From this data, I would like to extract two events: a "AR-PK" and a "PK-DP". Note however that for some events, there's only one PK connecting both AR and DP, meaning that two events can be created from three records (the PK movement is overlapping).

| acreg | flight | movement_type | start_datetime | end_datetime | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PHTFM | OR1072 | AR-PK | 2022-08-08 02:24:44 | 2022-08-08 04:07:00 | D02 |
| PHTFM | OR377 | PK-DP | 2022-08-08 12:15:00 | 2022-08-08 14:42:22 | D07 |

Comment: please provide a reproducible sample of your input and the matching expected output

Comment: @mozway, I added sample data!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is following the line:

```
    if end_AR in df_amove_PK["start_datetime"]:
    print(df_amove_PK["start_datetime"].index)
```

Unfortunately, Pandas doesn't have the `if statement in` function, but there are alternative options.

First option is to use `loc condition`.

```
df_amove_PK.loc[df_amove_PK["start_datetime"] == end_AR, 'result'] = 'True'
```

Second option is using `lambda`.

```
df_amove_PK['result'] = df_amove_PK['start_datetime'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x == end_AR else 'False')
```

And following the lines are a guide for you.

```
# df_amove_PK.loc[df_amove_PK["start_datetime"] == value you want to find, 'new column name'] = 'value that match the condition'
# df_amove_PK['new column name'] = df_amove_PK['start_datetime'].apply(lambda x: value that want to apply  if x == value that you find else value that want to apply)
```

And [this](https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/) is great reference that I was helped with.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot! This solution worked for creating a new column. Of course, my goal is to add multiple columns (I added some sample data as an example). Do you maybe have a suggestion for this as well?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It appeared to be a simple `merge` operation with some extra steps. I first filtered on "PK", "AR", and "DP", then performed two merges, and finally concatenated these. The code I used:

```
# Create three sets of data from df_amove to run the for loops 
df_amove_AR = df_amove[df_amove["movement_type"] == "AR"]
df_amove_PK = df_amove[df_amove["movement_type"] == "PK"]
df_amove_DP = df_amove[df_amove["movement_type"] == "DP"]

# Create columns to merge on for arriving flights
df_amove_PK["merge_AR"] = df_amove_PK["start_datetime"]
df_amove_AR["merge_AR"] = df_amove_AR["end_datetime"]

# Create columns to merge on for departing flights
df_amove_PK["merge_DP"] = df_amove_PK["end_datetime"]
df_amove_DP["merge_DP"] = df_amove_DP["start_datetime"]

# Perform the merge
df_merge_AR_PK = pd.merge(df_amove_AR, df_amove_PK, on=["merge_AR","acreg"], suffixes=("_AR", "_PK"))
df_AR_PK = df_merge_AR_PK[["acreg", "flight_AR", "start_datetime_AR", "end_datetime_PK", "current_position_AR"]]
df_AR_PK["movement"] = "AR-PK"
df_AR_PK.rename(columns={"flight_AR":"flight", "start_datetime_AR":"start_datetime", "end_datetime_PK":"end_datetime", "current_position_AR":"stand"}, inplace=True)

df_merge_PK_DP = pd.merge(df_amove_PK, df_amove_DP, on=["merge_DP","acreg"], suffixes=("_PK", "_DP"))
df_PK_DP = df_merge_PK_DP[["acreg", "flight_DP", "start_datetime_PK", "end_datetime_DP", "current_position_DP"]]
df_PK_DP["movement"] = "PK-DP"
df_PK_DP.rename(columns={"flight_DP":"flight", "start_datetime_PK":"start_datetime", "end_datetime_DP":"end_datetime", "current_position_DP":"stand"}, inplace=True)

# Create the new dataframe df_events
df_events = pd.concat([df_AR_PK, df_PK_DP])
df_events.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_events
```